# The concept of an object variable in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In my typoscript `20.special.value` and `10.value.typolink.parameter` have the same value, which is a page id. I use this value to build a heading and a menu of its subpages within the same `COA` object. I would like to be able to re-use this value.

**How can I call a object property in typoscript?**

Here's what I have tried:

```
  10 = HTML
  10 {
    value.typolink {
      parameter = {$temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.20.special.value}
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**:

I am re-utilizing my COA object in different parts of the site, and changing only the `special.value`, so to display a menu I have:

```
temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.10.value.typolink.parameter = 2427
temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.20.special.value = 2427  
temp.COLUMN_NOTSURE < temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU
```

I am after a cleaner way of handling the

```
temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.10.value.typolink.parameter = 2427
temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.20.special.value = 2427
```

Full LANDINGPAGEMENU typoscript code is http://pastebin.com/p9kPuZEe

Comment: This is what I am trying to do in plain PHP: http://pastebin.com/BwTwEeZ1

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the constants but not in a way you tried. You have to define the constant first.

   Constants: `my_constant = 2427`

   Setup: `parameter = {$my_constant}`

   **...OR...**
2. Assign one of the values by **[reference](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_ts/4.7.0/view/1/2/#id501855)** using the `=<` operator. However, this would work only when using the whole object. Example:

   `temp.something = TEXT`

   `temp.something.value = 2427`

   `...parameter.cObject =< temp.something`

---

I suggest you go with the option 1 using the constants as the 2nd option is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: I didn't know this but when you look at his pastebin this doesn't work on properties?

Comment: Chibox, this answer suggests another way, my pastebin has `.<`

Comment: @Chibox, you are right. This cannot work for the attribute unless it's an object as well - which requires that it has stdWrap. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, constants don't really work, I am trying to reuse a COA object (pastebin) throughout the site.

Comment: Constants work very well if you use them correctly. You have to define them in the **constants** part of the template. It's not like any object from the setup can be used as a constant as in your original example.

Comment: See the documentation on constants: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_ts/4.7.0/view/1/3/#id449287

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the property but not by reference it.

Comment: I've tried `parameter < temp.LANDINGPAGEMENU.20.special.value` but it also didn't work.

Comment: Try .<: Parameter .< Temp.Landingpagemenu.20.special.value

Comment: Filype: Why don't you use constants?

Comment: Filype: Or you can use a register?